# Npm packages are installed in the wrong node version folder of nvm

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, nvm

I have installed `node 10.14.2` & `node 12.13.1` with `nvm`(Node version manage)

Default version set to `node 12.13.1`

This it the output when I run `nvm list`

```
       v10.14.2
->     v12.13.1
         system
default -> 12 (-> v12.13.1)
node -> stable (-> v12.13.1) (default)
stable -> 12.13 (-> v12.13.1) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
lts/* -> lts/erbium (-> v12.13.1)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.16.2 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/erbium -> v12.13.1
```

Now when I install a global npm package, it is installed in the `v.10.14.2` folder instead of the `v.12.13.1` one, why does it still refer to the old version folder??

In my `.bash_profile` file I have this if it can help

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

Comment: After setting the default, did you switch to any existing windows/terminals and run the npm install there?

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: What I am checking is that you **didn't switch to an existing**, but rather opened a new terminal after setting the default?

Comment: I use the same terminal

Comment: I have the exact same problem. So far, this thread is the only reference to it anywhere I've looked on the web. Must not be a common issue.

Comment: @MikeS. did you find a solution for this?

Comment: It’s a non-issue for me. I no longer work on that codebase. So I don’t remember if I fixed it or not. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I noticed i had a file `~/.npmrc` which had one line in it...

```
prefix=/Users/spoogaloo/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1
```

This was the folder all my global node modules were being installed into, whichever version of node i had selected using nvm.

I deleted this file, opened a new terminal and the problem was fixed – new global node modules were installing into their correct folders, according to nvm's current node version.

I think it's because i had previously installed `node` using homebrew, and hadn't uninstalled it properly before installing `nvm`.